# Java - check if under_score string is in a list of lowerCamel strings

Tags: java, collections, java-stream, camelcasing

Consider the following keys (under_score) and fields (lowerCamel):

```
keys   = ["opened_by","ticket_owner","close_reason"]
fields = ["openedBy","ticketOwner","closeReason"]
```

I'm looking for an efficient way in Java to check whether `key` is in `fields`, where I expect the following to return `true`:

```
fields = ["openedBy","ticketOwner"]

return fields.contains("opened_by"))   //true
```

My code:

```
Set<String> incidentFields = Arrays
            .stream(TicketIncidentDTO.class.getDeclaredFields())
            .map(Field::getName)
            .collect(Collectors.toSet()
            );


responseJson.keySet().forEach(key ->{
           
            if (incidentFields.contains(key)) 
            {
                //Do something
            }
        });
```

I could just replace all lowerCase with underscore, but I'm looking for more efficient way of doing this.

Comment: Does this solve your problem? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10310321/regex-for-converting-camelcase-to-camel-case-in-java

Comment: Thanks, but not exactly, I could just replace all lowerCase with underscore, but I'm looking for more efficient way of doing this. Maybe some method which ignore case format or something like that.

Comment: Sets, Maps, by default call the `equals()` method. There is no "simple" here. Either you implement your very special Set that uses different kind of comparisons, or you bite the bullet and keep multiple sets that have those "transformed" IDs within. And note that ignoring case doesnt really help, as it leaves the "_" around to fail comparisons on.

Comment: Could you clarify what you deem too inefficient in "replacing lowerCase with underscore"? As I see it, you have two choices: (1) Initially transforming your fields to be in underscore instead of CamelCase notation, (2) keeping fields as is and instead transforming the keys from underscore to CamelCase during each lookup. Approach (1) is by far the more efficient one if you have relatively few fields and many look ups.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do not have fields like `abcXyz` (`abc_xyz`) and `abCxyz` (`ab_cxyz`) (fields with same spelling but combination of different words), then one solution would be to replace the `"_"` with empty `""` and then compare to fieldName using `equalsIgnoreCase`. Another but similar solution would be to convert each fieldName to lower case and then compare it to the camel case string after replacing the "_" with "". This could possibly eliminate the use of an additional loop when compared to the first approach.

```java
Set<String> fields= Arrays.stream(TicketIncidentDTO.class.getDeclaredFields())
                          .map(Field::getName)
                          .map(String::toLowerCase)
                          .collect(Collectors.toSet());


responseJson.keySet()
            .filter(key -> fields.contains(key.replaceAll("_","")))
            .forEach(key -> {
                // do something..
            });
```

Answer (score 3):

Try with [CaseUtils](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-text/apidocs/org/apache/commons/text/CaseUtils.html) from [Commons Text](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-text/1.9)

```
// opened_by -> openedBy
private String toCamel(String str) {
    return CaseUtils.toCamelCase(str, false, new char[] { '_' });
}

List<String> keys = Arrays.asList("opened_by", "ticket_owner", "close_reason", "full_name");

List<String> fields = Arrays.asList("openedBy", "ticketOwner", "closeReason");

keys.forEach(t -> {
    // check
    if (fields.contains(toCamel(t))) {
        System.out.println(t);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple `toCamel` method:

```
private String toCamel(String str) {
    String[] parts = str.split("_");
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(parts[0]);
    for (int i=1; i < parts.length ; i++) {
        String part = parts[i];
        if (part.length() > 0) {
            sb.append(part.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase()).append(part.substring(1));
        }
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Now use the very same approach:

```
keys.forEach(t -> {
    if (fields.contains(toCamel(t))) {
        System.out.println("Fields contain " + t);
    } else {
        System.out.println("Fields doesn't contain " + t);
    }
});
```

> I could just replace all lowerCase with underscore, but I'm looking for more efficient way of doing this.

Use `Set` as a data structure for `keys` and `fields` that is very effective in the look-up. Moreover, it is sutable for this use case since it doesn't make sense to have duplicated keys in JSON.